# C++: plotting a 3d surface from a points set in qt

Tags: c++, qt, plot, 3d, surface

Does anyone knows relatively simple way to plot a 3d surface in C++ from a set of points (x,y,z)?

Comment: Qt has an OpenGL module. The [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html) would be a good place to start. In particular, [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html) shows how to create a cube.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt Data Visualization](http://doc.qt.io/QtDataVisualization/) module provides a way to visualize data in 3D.

- [Custom Items Example](http://doc.qt.io/QtDataVisualization/qtdatavisualization-customitems-example.html)
- [3D Surface Example](http://doc.qt.io/QtDataVisualization/qtdatavisualization-qmlsurface-example.html)